# Do integer and floating-point values of the same size have the same granularity between their respective min and max values?

Tags: encoding, binary, floating-point, integer

I was wondering about some of the math or theory of whether a signed integer or signed floating-point representation in *n* bits encodes more granularity between its min and max values (or if the two encode the same granularity).

Imagine a use-case in which I want to represent audio samples at the maximum possible granularity in 32 bits. MAX/MIN will be the sample with the largest absolute value observed, and 0 will represent silence. The goal is to have each sample represent the closest to the true value of the sound pressure (or voltage) at any moment and to minimize information loss due to rounding.

My instinct as that integer and floating-point representations will contain the same level of granularity because each can encode 2^32 distinct values between MIN and MAX.

1. Am I correct to observe that the absolute number of distinct values of information they can encode is equal?
2. Is the granularity for one more concentrated in a particular range for one representation than another? My instinct is that a floating point representation would concentrate more of its granularity around zero and retain less granularity near its MAX/MIN values. Put another way, a floating point representation will differentiate between very similar values (e.g. .001 and .002) as long as those values are close to zero, but not differentiate between very similar values if those values are not close to zero (e.g. 8388607.001 and 8388607.002). Is this correct?

Comment: Floating point encodes different granularity for different magnitudes. Small magnitude numbers are very close together. Large magnitude numbers are very far apart.

Comment: Thank you, so the difference is where the granularity is concentrated: for integers, granularity is spread linearly throughout a range, and for floating point it is concentrated around small numbers at the expense of large numbers.

Comment: The point in floating point floats. That is the point of floating point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider conventional unsigned 32-bit binary, and IEEE 754 32-bit floating point.

The integer format encodes all the integers from 0 through 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, and nothing else.

The floating point format encodes 2<sup>23</sup> numbers for each power-of-two range. It encodes just as many numbers in [2<sup>-100</sup>,2<sup>-99</sup>) as in [2<sup>100</sup>,2<sup>101</sup>). It actually encodes fewer numeric values than 32 bit integer because it reserves a block of values for infinities and NaNs (Not-a-Number).

Comment: Thank you. I actually got quite a bit of information simply by reading your answer history. SO is, as always, a great place to find an expert on a particular topic.